# Standard partial regression plot vs. effect plot from 'effects' package

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-visualization, marginal-effect, partial-effect

I'll use a modification of [this example](https://rpubs.com/Hank_Stevens/prp) to ask my question about an apparent alternative way of presenting a partial regression plot, using the `effects` package.

First, we set up two, positively correlated predictor variables, `x1` (which is of our primary interest) and `x2` (a covariate of lesser interest), and their effects on the response variabe, `y`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100, 30, 100)
set.seed(2)
x1 <- x + rnorm(100, sd=10)
set.seed(3)
c <- 1         # positive correlation between predictors
x2 <- c * x + rnorm(100, sd=10)

p1 <- 1        # positive effect of x1
p2 <- -1       # neg. effect of x2
set.seed(1)

y <- 50 + p1*x1 + p2*x2 + rnorm(100, sd=10) # independent effects of x1 and x2, plus noise)

plot(x1, y, main='y ~ x1')
```

[image]

To visualize the unique effect of `x1` while accounting for `x2`, a partial regression plot is generally presented by plotting the residuals of `x1 ~ x2` on the horizontal axis, against the residuals of `y ~ x2` on the vertical axis.

```
# y, given x2
mod1 <- lm(y ~ x2 )
y.resid <- resid(mod1)
# x1, given x2
mod2 <- lm(x1 ~ x2)
x.resid <- resid(mod2)

plot(x.resid, y.resid, main='Partial regression: y|x2 ~ x1|x2')
```

[image]

However, the interpretation of this figure is not straight forward.

I found that an alternative partial regression plot can be presented using the `effects` package, after running the multiple linear regression model `mod0 <- lm(y ~ x1 +x2)`:

```
library(effects)
effx1 <- effect("x1", mod0, partial.residuals=T)
plot(effx1, smooth.residuals=F)
```

[image]

Which is really more appealing, because the horizontal axis gives the actual values of `x1`. Also, the vertical axis appear to show the unique (positive) contribution of each `x1` to `y`, but I don't quite understand how `x2` is corrected for. I notice that it is not only a matter of scaling the vertical axis differently, as the pattern of the data points is different.

**My questions:**

1. Is this effect plot really an equivalent presentation of the above partial regression plot?
2. How is it computed? In other words, how would one produce it manually?

Many thanks!

Comment: I show how to create partial residual and partial regression (aka added variable plot) manually in my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/414164/21054).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple regression avPlots vs termplot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271314/multiple-regression-avplots-vs-termplot)