# How to construct a scatterplot with regression line that adjusts for other covariates?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-visualization, lm, ggplot2

I am attempting to produce a scatterplot with a regression line whose intercept & slope are adjusted to account for another covariate in the model. (I understand that the data points don't change, just the intercept & slope of the regression line.)

So far, I have had no problem creating the scatterplot/regression line when there is only one predictor:

original analysis:

```
test7 <- lm(outcome1 ~ predictor1, data=dataset)
summary(test7)
```

corresponding plot:

```
 plot7 <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x=predictor1, y=outcome1)) +
      geom_point(shape=19, alpha=1/4) +
      geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

However, I would like to create a similar scatterplot/regression line that corresponds to the following analysis:

```
test8 <- lm(outcome1 ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data=dataset)
summary(test8)
```

The following plot printed, but I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
plot8 <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x=predictor1 + predictor2, y=outcome1)) +
  geom_point(shape=19, alpha=1/4) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Is this the way to make the adjustment to the regression line intercept & slope? Or is there another way?

Comment: I have often wanted to do this, but was pulled up short by the realization that a "covariate," by its very definition, *changes.*  Thus, there is no such thing as a regression "line": the fit has to depend on the (invisible) covariate!  In light of this, could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish with this graphic?

Comment: Maybe you want [partial residual plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot)?

Comment: The the the slope of the regression line (the regression coefficient) for outcome1 ~ predictor is different, depending on whether predictor2 is or isn't in the model. I want to be able to generate a scatterplot with a regression line that reflects either of these two regression coefficient.

For example, if predictor 1's regression coefficient is positive WITHOUT predictor2 in the model but negative WITH predictor2 in the model, I'd want to make sure I could show a scatterplot with the negative regression line slope included to line up with the results of the analysis.

Comment: I would suggest that the goal of the regression needs to be changed to reflect the questions asked of it. For example, least squares in $y$ (OLS) returns a minimum error $y$ predictor. In most cases (and there are exceptions) OLS does not return the functional relationship between $x$ and $y$, for that, Deming regression would be used. Suggestion: 1) define the target or goal of regression, 2) develop an algorithm to accomplish that goal and you will have your answer.

Comment: I show some examples in [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/414164/21054).

Answer (score 4):

One way to account for (or "control for") a covariate in a regression is to "take it out of the model" by regressing all other variables against that covariate and retaining only the residuals from those regressions.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919 for an illustrated explanation and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207/919 for a more theoretical (geometric) account.

Intuitively, **we remove all variation in the outcome that can be associated (in a specified way) with the covariate and then study how what remains of the outcome is associated with what remains of the other explanatory variables.**

This is easily done.

Let's begin with a dataset in which `outcome` depends on two variables `predictor1` and `predictor2`, as in the question:

[image: Figure 1]

As always, we may plot the outcome against a single regressor (here `predictor1`).  We may, if we wish, conduct a *univariate* regression simply by ignoring the other regressor(s):

[image: Figure 2]

The line is the Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) fit, computed in `R` as

```
fit.1 <- lm(outcome ~ predictor1, data=X)
```

To control for--that is, understand the effect of including--another covariate, model the outcome against that covariate and plot the residuals of that model against the regressor:

[image: Figure 3]

The calculations in `R` required two (univariate) OLS regressions:

```
fit.2 <- lm(outcome ~ predictor2, data=X)
X$residual2 <- residuals(fit.2)
fit.12 <- lm(residual2 ~ predictor1, data=X)
```

The change in slope between the last two figures was possible due to multicollinearity of the predictors: that was apparent in the first figure, whose points exhibit a correlation of about $-0.75.$

This approach is consistent with the ideas behind [Added Variable Plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_regression_plot) (*aka* Partial Regression Plots), but to make it comparable to the original (univariate) scatterplot, I have not "taken out the effect of `predictor2` on `predictor1`".  When that's done (with yet one more application of univariate OLS), the plot is more abstract but gives an even clearer picture of the relationship between `outcome` and `predictor1` after controlling for `predictor2`:

[image: Figure 4]

The `R` code to produce this final figure begins

```
X$residual1 <- residuals(lm(predictor1 ~ predictor2, X))
ggplot(X, aes(x=residual1, y=residual2)) +
```

(and the rest is just cosmetic).

---

People have contributed several `R` packages to automate the construction of added-variable plots.  For the current offerings [search CRAN](https://www.google.com/search?q=cran+added+variable+plot).

#### References

Montgomery, Peck, and Vining, *Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis,* Fifth Edition (2012): section 4.2.4.

Mosteller and Tukey, *Data Analysis and Regression, A Second Course in Statistics* (1977): section 12C, "Graphical fitting by stages."