# How to visualize impact of independent variable on dependent variable?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization

I have set of independent variables ( X1 , X2 )  and a dependent variable (Y) . I am using Multi linear regression to study the impact of X on Y .
( Detail : I would like to show both the magnitude and direction how a unit change in X1 results in change in Y )

I would like to know if there is a good visualization to share with the business folks ?  I can only think of bar plot for the model coefficients.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about what aspects or properties of this dataset or your model of it you wish to visualize?  "Impact" could mean many different things.

Comment: @whuber - Just updated my question. Thanks

Comment: A closely related thread is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397183.  Maybe that's the sort of thing you're looking for?  It depends on whether you need to show the data in your plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll outline a few ways to do this.

My favorite way is to plot the coefficients *and the confidence intervals*.  I know that business people are not always statistically savvy, so while in my opinion this is *the* way to present regression model results it may go over your partner's heads.

[image]

Another way may be to just plot some different lines under different values.  Here is an example of what I mean.  This way, they can clearly see that as V2 increases, the predictions decrease, and as V1 increases then the predictions do as well.

[image]

There are endless charts.  I think the question is not "what chart do I use?" but rather "what information do I want people to walk away with?".

Comment: Thanks. This is great.I accepted the answer can't upvote with < 15 reputation

Comment: @Zebra If you found this helpful, please upvote and accept the answer.