# If $\beta$ can be expressed $\frac{\text{cov}(Y, \widetilde X) }{\text{var}(\widetilde X)}$... So where does the shared component of the variance go?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I think this is a fairly technical, conceptual question so I'm going to do my best to explain what I'm thinking.

For the regression $\widetilde Y = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 X_1 + \hat \beta_2 X_2$, the equation for the coeficient $\hat \beta_2$ is $\text{cov}(Y,\widetilde X_2)/\text{var}(\widetilde X_2)$ where $\widetilde X_2$ are the $e$'s from the regression $X_2 = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 X_1 + e$. Conceptually, these errors are the variance of $X_2$ that can't be explained by the other covariates, up to an affine transformation.
Thus, only the "unique variation" in $X_2$ is what gives us additional power in predicting $Y$.

The same can be said of $\hat \beta_1$ and $X_1$.

What I'm trying to understand is what happened to the parts of the variance that were similar in $X_1$ and $X_2$? By similar I just mean that $X_2$ could explain in $X_1$ and what $X_1$ could explain in $X_2$.

It seems like it needs to show up somewhere in the regression results but I can't find where it is... I think it'd end up in the $\hat \beta_0$ but I'm not sure if that's accurate or how to show it.

Comment: See, *inter alia,* https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/448240/919, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919.

Comment: @whuber I like the discussions here and they do a great job giving a geometric understanding of how the parameters get determined but I'm not sure if they connect the idea back to variance very well. Could you help me make the connection?

Comment: for that we need explicit modeling of interaction https://stattrek.com/multiple-regression/interaction.aspx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics) regards,
shibamouli