# 'Controlling' For Other Features in Residual Scatter plots

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals

I'm performing linear regression and hope to make claims about specific variables while keeping the others constant. I was wondering if this was possible. For clarity, I have three predictors:
$\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$
I want to see if the residuals of $\beta_1$ have non-constant variance or if a non-linear relation exists **while controlling $\beta_2, \beta_3$**. Is this possible?

Comment: *Multivariate* regression involves a *vector* response.  Are you perhaps asking about *multiple* regression?  If so, the answer is yes, as explained in various threads including https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397183.  Maybe the latter is exactly what you want to know?

Comment: @whuber yes, you're right, thank you I was looking for partial residual plots. And thanks for all your contributions to various networks, but especially this one. I see your responses on so many posts that I read!